# How do I create a textfield when a certain selection is made inside a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a basic web form that contains a couple of drop-down select elements. Both of these elements have an 'other - please specify' option, and I wish for a textfield to automatically appear under the drop-down box whenever the 'other' option is selected, and to have the textfield disappear if the option is changed from 'other' to a different option.

I am at a loss as to how to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: This Stackoverflow post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132331/on-change-the-select-value-display-certain-div-content

Answer (score 1):

Working code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMKN3/)

JS:

```
document.getElementById("sid").onchange= function(){

    if(this.value == 'Other'){
       document.getElementById("other").style.display = '';
    }
    else{
          document.getElementById("other").style.display = 'none';
    }
}​
```

HTML:

```
<select id='sid'>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>
<input id='other' style='display:none' /> ​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to accomplish this.  Try this page http://www.coderanch.com/t/112986/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Show-hidden-text-field.

Answer (score 0):

on your select tag you can add an onchange="changed()" attribute.
Then create a javascript function called changed.

Use Jquery for the rest.

For example

```
function changed() {
    if($('#idOfSelect').val() == "Other") {
        $('#idOfSelect').after("<textbox>bla bla</textbox>");
    }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: There's nothing that indicates that the op is using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pZdK/)

HTML

```
<select id="aDropDown">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=other>Other</option>
</select>
<p id="aDropDownOther" class="other-label">Other Label</p>​
```

JS

```
var ele_aDropDownOther = document.getElementById('aDropDownOther');

document.getElementById('aDropDown').onchange = function() {
    if (this[this.selectedIndex].value === "other") {
        ele_aDropDownOther.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        ele_aDropDownOther.style.display = "";
    }
}​
```

CSS

```
.other-label {display:none;}​
```

---

OR similarly using jQuery

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pZdK/1/)

JavaScript/jQuery

```
var $aDropDown = $('#aDropDown'),
    $aDropDownOther = $('#aDropDownOther');

$aDropDown.change(function() {
    if ($aDropDown.val() === "other") {
        $aDropDownOther.show();
    } else {
        $aDropDownOther.hide();
    }
});​
```